# How do join two tables then count the number of distinct values for a particular month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `table_b` with 25,644 rows and 3 columns, `Customer_ID`, `Department` and `Month`. This table has duplicate rows of `Customer_ID`, `Department` and `Month` and has no missing values.

I also have a **distinct** `table_a` with 63,077 rows and 3 columns, `Customer_ID`, `Segment` and `Month`. In the `Segment` column, 263 rows have a value of `#N/A` while 90 rows are `NULL`.

I am trying to join `table_a` to `table_b`, however I am getting a total of 33,225 rows.

Here is my code:

```
select *
from table_b as a
left join table_a as b on a.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
```

This is returning 33,225 rows. Should it be returning the number of rows in `table_b` which is 25,644?

I also tried:

```
select * 
from table_b as a
left join table_a as b on a.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
where b.Segment is not null and b.Segment ! = '#N/A`
```

This however returns a total of 33,127 rows.

Can anyone please explain why?

Ultimately I am trying to join both tables, then count the number of `distinct Segment` on `table_a` that belong to a particular `Department` on `table_b`.

Answer (score 0):

> Ultimately I am trying to join both tables, then count the number of distinct Segment for the Month of January.

I don't see why a `join` is necessary.  All the information needed for the query appears to be in `table_a`:

```
select a.month, count(distinct a.seqment)
from table_a a
where a.Segment is not null and a.Segment <> '#N/A'
group by a.month;
```

If you want one particular month, then filter for that.  You haven't provided sample data, but perhaps:

```
where a.month = 'January'
```

Comment: You accidently used a tick to end the N/A string.

Comment: Indeed you did, I see that now. Easy to miss. I've seen questions about a query where the quote string being used was incorrect. Seems to happen from time to time.

Comment: @Gordon.Linoff in my effort to try and be concise, I failed to describe my problem accurately.  Yes the "Segment" is on table_a, however lets say I have an additional column on table_b, call it "Department". So each Segment on table_a corresponds to a Department on table_b. So I need to count the number of rows where the Segment (on table_a) belongs to a particular Department (on table_b). Does this make sense?

Comment: @TheRookie Please edit your question and then let Gordon know you added more context. No reason to re-explain in a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited/corrected my question